# How to get query sys_id of current.sys_id Service Portal (ServiceNow)

Tags: servicenow

I have a question regarding a small issue that I'm having. I've created a widget that will live on the Service Portal to allow an admin to Accept or Reject requests.

The data for the widget is pulling from the Approvals (approval_approver) table. Under my GlideRecord, I have a query that checks for the state as requested. (Ex. addQuery('state', 'requested'))

To narrow down the search, I tried entering addQuery('sys_id', current.sys_id). When I use this query, my script breaks and I get an error on the Service Portal end.

Here's a sample of the GlideRecord script I've written to Accept.

```
[//Accept Request
if(input && input.action=="acceptApproval") {
    var inRec1 = new GlideRecord('sysapproval_approver');
    inRec1.addQuery('state', 'requested');
    //inRec1.get('sys_id', current.sys_id);
    inRec1.query();
    if(inRec1.next()) {
        inRec1.setValue('state', 'Approved');
        inRec1.setValue('approver', gs.getUserID());
        gs.addInfoMessage("Accept Approval Processed");
        inRec1.update();
    }
}][1]
```

I've research the web, tried using $sp.getParameter() as a work-around and no change.

I would really appreciate any help or insight on what I can do different to get script to work and filter the right records.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how to get the sysId of the `sysapproval_approver` record from the client-side in a widget.

Unless you have defined `current` elsewhere in your server script, current is undefined. Secondly, `$sp.getParameter()` is used to retrieve URL parameters. So unless you've included the sysId as a URL parameter, that will not get you what you are looking for.

One pattern that I've used is to pass an object to the client after the initial query that gets the list of requests.

When you're ready to send input to the server from the client, you can add relevant information to the input object. See the simplified example below. For the sake of brevity, the code below does not include error handling.

```js
// Client-side function
approveRequest = function(sysId) {
    $scope.server.get({
        action: "requestApproval",
        sysId: sysId
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log("Request approved");
    });
};

// Server-side
var requestGr = new GlideRecord();
requestGr.addQuery("SOME_QUERY");
requestGr.query(); // Retrieve initial list of requests to display in the template

data.requests = []; // Add array of requests to data object to be passed to the client via the controller
while(requestsGr.next()) {
    data.requests.push({
        "number": requestsGr.getValue("number");
        "state" : requestsGr.getValue("state");
        "sysId" : requestsGr.getValue("sys_id");
    });
}

  
if(input && input.action=="acceptApproval") {
    var sysapprovalGr = new GlideRecord('sysapproval_approver');

    if(sysapprovalGr.get(input.sysId)) {
        sysapprovalGr.setValue('state', 'Approved');
        sysapprovalGr.setValue('approver', gs.getUserID());
        sysapprovalGr.update();

        gs.addInfoMessage("Accept Approval Processed");
        
    }

...
```